# Canvas: trying to draw too large(n-bytes) bitmap

Tags: java, android, crop

When i try to crop big image file, app is crashed.

When I look in logcat, I see the following message:

```
          ` --------- beginning of crash
    04-16 10:28:54.748 5581-5581/com.android.quizz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.quizz, PID: 5581
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(119501824bytes) bitmap.
    at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1286)
    at com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageView.onDraw(CropImageView.java:185)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17071)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17074)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:751)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:656)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:662)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:770)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2796)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2604)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2211)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
    04-16 10:28:54.749 1663-1799/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.android.xxx/com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity`
```

Selected image info:

- Size: 1.6 MB
- Resolution: 71 MP
- Dimensions: 11658x6112

Does this have anything to do with [crop library](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop) ?

Comment: try loading the image with glide or Picasso libraries

Comment: The compressed size is not the same as the decompressed one, you will need to downsample your image.